# How to Enable AutoPostBack property and CheckChanged Event to an input[type=checkbox]?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, checkbox, postback

I have an `input[type="checkbox"]` which have applied it `runat="server"` to access its value from code-behind. I want to make it raise postback on every `checkchanged` event but I can't find a property proper for that.

The reason I want to use it instead of a asp:checkbox control is because of its CSS which I found it hard to emulate its style for asp:checkbox control.
This is the source of control:

```
<label class="switch switch-green">
               <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" id="cbAvailabilityFlag" runat="server" >
               <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span><span class="switch-handle"></span>    
    </label>
```

Comment: you have not closed the `input` tag `</>`

Comment: @nadeem Thanks, Consider it a typo

Comment: you can  store the `checkbox` value in a `HiddenField` , then access this hidden field value on the server.